# Java: What is the best approach to validate the method arguments for null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, method-invocation, null-check

What is the best approach to validate the arguments for null while calling a method?

1) before making the method call

```
private void myMethod(String param1, String param2){
   String a = param2;
   if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(a)){   
      validate(a);
   }
}

private void validate(String a) {
    int temp = Integer.parseInt(a);
    if(a > 4){
          addError()
    }
}
```

2) inside the method once you receive the arguments

```
private void myMethod(String param1, String param2){
   String a = param2;
   validate(a);       
}

private void validate(String a) {
     if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(a)){
         int temp = Integer.parseInt(a);
         if(a > 4){
            addError()
         }
     }
}
```

OR Both

Comment: This depends entirely on your context. Should the method handle null smoothly, or is it a sign that something has gone wrong if it receives null? Do you have access to the code of the method you're calling? Is the logic always the same when you call the method with a null value?

Answer (score 4):

IMO, `StringUtils.isNotBlank(a)` is some form of validation only, so it should be in `validate()` method. And if that has to be checked every time you call `validate()` method, then certainly it will make more sense to move it there.

Answer (score 2):

From the two approaches you give, the second is better.

Reason: [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (Don't Repeat Yourself aka avoid code duplication).

The code in the first snipped duplicates (or triplicates, etc) the "check for blank" part of the code for every place `validate()` is called.

Also the responsibility of the consistency, the "not blank" invariant (a domain/business rule), belongs (is inherent) to the `validate()` method, so it should have the responsibility for taking care of it.

In practical terms: Consider the possibility of a change to this domain rule, if one needed to add some new check to it, in what case you'd have to change less (thus less error-prone)? Where the developer that'll do the change would expect to find such rule? In the `validate()` or scattered through the whole code base?

Answer (score 0):

If that error validation is useful everytime you call some method, it obviously should be done inside the method, or else you would have to do it everytime before calling that method. Just remember to comment the code, so you remember that later.

Answer (score 0):

Would be inside the method throwing a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.
Like:

```
private void validate(String a) {
 if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(a)){
     int temp = Integer.parseInt(a);
     if(a > 4){
        addError()
     }
 }
else{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument must not be null or blank");
}
```

}

Comment: `a != null` will anyways be handled by `StringUtils.isNotBlank`.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually the validate() method should capable to identify that the passing parameter is null or not. So in your given scenario the approach `2` should be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best approach to validate the arguments

IMO, your second approach is better one
because it is not a **task** for which you have to provide a separate method, it is just a **parameter validation** which is part of same logic which you are going to implement in your method. and another thing to be considered is second approach will form higher redability of your code.

> OR Both

**NEVER**, Choose one as per your coding practice and stick to it.

*Other considerations for validation :*

1. [Check parameters annotated with @Nonnull for null?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/168395/116707)
2. You can use [assertion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html) for `Private` arguments.